# How to subset based on state abbreviation?

Tags: r

I need to calculate the number of people in the data whose home country is the U.S (there are 100s of rows you just don't see the US countries now. I do not know how to only pick out US states and not include the other international countries.

I am so lost I am not sure if I should use tidyverse or an apply function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be good if you restored the display of the top few lines of your data set, but as cut-and-pasted text (in code format, i.e. indented 4 spaces or using triple-back-quotes). Without this it would have been basically impossible to answer your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably

```
us_data <- data[data$HomeStateOrCountry %in% state.abb, ]
```

? or if you like tidyverse

```
filter(data,HomeStateOrCountry %in% state.abb)
```